# Why rendered image is not like in the material preview frame?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I try to make stainless steel effect, but I don't understand why rendered image in the top panel is not like in the material preview frame in the right panel ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same because you haven't applied smooth shade to your material. However there could be more reasons(like: weird settings setup in the render tab or word tab)

Comment: I think the correct question is why it doesnt look the same.Thats because the above, plus because your light setups are different.

Comment: What are the the good light setups ?

Comment: On tutorials about how to make Glossy Images, there 2 planes perpendiculars which wrap up the Glossy objects, maybe that is the solution

Comment: The 2 perpendiculars mesh planes are indeed the solution, in fact it creates a good lighting effect